# How do I concatenate wide string literals with PRId32, PRIu64, etc.?

Tags: c, string, visual-c++, unicode, macros

Suppose I need to print a formatted string with an `int32_t` using the printf format specifier from `<inttypes.h>`.

```
int32_t i = 0;
printf("%" PRId32 "\n", i);
```

If I try to do the same with wide characters in Visual C++ 2013, it fails:

```
#define W_(val) L ## val
#define W(val) W_(val)
wprintf(L"%" W(PRId32) L"\n", i);
```

> error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings

How do I concatenate wide string literals with format conversion specifier macros?

Comment: As a rule I generally avoid `wchar_t` (except, for example, inside wrapper functions that provide a working narrow character file API on Windows). You might consider avoiding it as well due this this and other problems it has. Alternatively you might consider using C++ instead of C; Visual Studio only has limited support for C but the C++ code `std::wcout << i << L'\n';` is portable and works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is twofold.  First, as noted in rici's answer, C99 and C++11 both added support for concatenating narrow string literals and wide string literals together, so you should not need to widen the narrow literal by prepending the L.  Visual C++ does not yet support this feature for either C or C++.

Because the compiler does not yet support this feature, we should in the libraries make it possible for you to explicitly widen these string literals using a technique like the one in your answer.  Unfortunately, we've defined these macros in a way such that they may expand to multiple string literals.  E.g., `PRId32` expands to `"l" "d"`.

This is valid, but it does prevent you from widening, because there is no way to prepend an `L` to the second string literal (to make `"d"` into `L"d"`).  I'm afraid I don't see a way to make this work without (re)defining the macros yourself.

I've opened a bug internally so that if the compiler does not add support for concatenation of mixed-width literals during preprocessing in the next release, we can revisit these definitions to possibly make it possible to widen them explicitly.

Comment: It was actually C99, rather than C11, that added support for concatenating wide and narrow literals.

Comment: @bames53:  Thanks; I've corrected the answer.  The wording changed between C99 and C11, and I wasn't paying particularly close attention when I skimmed C99 to check.

Comment: We've updated the macros for the next major release of the Visual C++ libraries, so this will work with the next release.

Answer (score 3):

I know zip-all about VS C++, but you shouldn't actually need the `L` prefix for the concatenand of a wide string literal.

```
 L"%" PRId32 "\n"
```

should work (and it does with gcc).

From the C11 draft, §6.4.5/5: (as far as I can tell, this was roughly the same in C99, except that C99 didn't have utf-8 literals.)

> In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of
>   adjacent character and identically-prefixed string literal tokens are concatenated into a
>   single multibyte character sequence. If any of the tokens has an encoding prefix, the
>   resulting multibyte character sequence is treated as having the same prefix; otherwise, it
>   is treated as a character string literal. Whether differently-prefixed wide string literal
>   tokens can be concatenated and, if so, the treatment of the resulting multibyte character
>   sequence are implementation-defined.

Also see §7.8.1/7, which provides the example:

```
uintmax_t i = UINTMAX_MAX; // this type always exists
wprintf(L"The largest integer value is %020"
    PRIxMAX "\n", i);
```

A similar clause appears in the C++11 standard, §2.14.5/13. (However, in C++03, combining narrow and wide string literals was not allowed.)

> In translation phase 6, adjacent string literals are concatenated. If both string literals have the same encoding-prefix, the resulting concatenated string literal has that encoding-prefix. If one string literal has no encoding-prefix, it is treated as a string literal of the same encoding-prefix as the other operand…

Apparently, Visual Studio does not allow this form of literal concatenation.

Comment: The quoted text is new in C++11 (note that in both C++11 and the latest C++14 draft it is paragraph 13, not in paragraph 8).  In C++98 the behavior is undefined.  Visual C++ does not yet implement this C++11 feature.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: I'm just about to replace that quote with one from the C11 draft, since I realized that the OP is about C, not C++.

Comment: Visual C++ does not support this C11 feature yet either.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: that's unfortunate for Visual C++ users.