# Widen version of __FUNCTION__ in Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, printf, c-preprocessor

I tried to write a wide version of `__FUNCTION__` to support portable code (Windows and Linux)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
typedef const wchar_t * PCWCH;
#define WIDEN2(x)       L ## x
#define WIDEN(x)        WIDEN2(x)
#ifdef _WIN32
#define __WFUNCTION__   WIDEN(__FUNCTION__) L"(): "
#elif __linux__
#define MAX_FUNC_NAME_SIZE  1024
WCHAR func_name[MAX_FUNC_NAME_SIZE];
#define __WFUNCTION__   \
    (AsciiStrToUnicodeStr(__FUNCTION__, func_name, MAX_FUNC_NAME_SIZE) == 0) ? func_name : L"(): " 
#endif


int AsciiStrToUnicodeStr(const char *src, WCHAR *destination, unsigned int dest_max)
{
    size_t retval;
    if (!src || !destination || (dest_max == 0)) {
        return -EINVAL;
    }
    retval = mbstowcs(destination, src, dest_max);
    return (retval == -1) ? retval : 0;
}

void DbgTrace(PCWCH  pwcFormat,...)
{

    wprintf(L"%ls\n", pwcFormat);

}

void test()
{

     DbgTrace(__WFUNCTION__ L"ERROR: Null string passed\r\n");
}

int main()
{
     DbgTrace(__WFUNCTION__ L"ERROR: Null string passed\r\n");
    test();
}
```

The output is only containing the name of the function, but not the concatenated string.

What is the mistake in the above code.

Added output of Preprocessor:

```
void test()
{

  DbgTrace((AsciiStrToUnicodeStr(__FUNCTION__, func_name, 1024) == 0) ? func_name : L"(): " L"ERROR: Null string passed\r\n");
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you just preprocess your code to expand the macros?  Can you post that?  Because your `__WFUNCTION__` identifier is reserved for implementation use per [**7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3).  You are thus invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Added output of preprocessor

Answer (score 0):

`__FUNCTION__` (which should be spelled `__func__` in C99) is not a string literal; it is effectively an implicitly-defined character array. So you can't create a string literal out of it with literal concatenation. (At least, not in standard C. MSVC might treat `__FUNCTION__`  as a string literal, but it's not portable.)

String literal concatenation is done by right after preprocessing, and can only be applied to string literals, not variables. `func_name " extra text"` would be a syntax error.

But that's not what the macro expansion produces, as you can see. The literals being concatenated are `L"(): " and`L"error: NULL string passed".

Note that if `__func__` were a string literal, you could turn it into a wide string literal with string concatenation. Eg:

```
L"" __FILE__ ": the file"
```

is a valid wide string literal. (But it won't work on Windows. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21789691/1566221).

Since `__func__` is not a string literal, there is no way to extend it in the preprocessor. (Nor to convert it to a wide string). Your best bet is to use it by itself ina `printf` call (or `wprintf`):

```
 printf("%s %s, funcname, message);
```